# C++ Linked List find() sharing nodes between two linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I have two structs `Invoice` & `InvoiceDetails` defined as follow:

```
struct InvoiceDetails {
    int invoiceId;
    int productId;
    int price;
    int quantity;
};

struct Invoice {
    int id;
    int createdAt;
};
```

And a Linked List for the data structure:

```
template<typename T>
struct Node {
    T data;
    Node *next;
};

template <typename T>
struct List {
    Node<T> *head = NULL;
    Node<T> *tail = NULL;
};
```

I need a method like "find All InvoiceDetails by invoiceId", and came up with the following:

```
template <typename T>
void add(List<T> &list, Node<T> *p) {
    if (list.head == NULL) {
        list.head = p;
        list.tail = list.head;
    } else {
        list.tail->next = p;
        list.tail = p;
    }
}

List<InvoiceDetails> findByInvoiceId(const List<InvoiceDetails> &list, int invoiceId) {
    List<InvoiceDetails> result;    
    Node<InvoiceDetails> *current = list.head;
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (current->data.invoiceId == invoiceId) {
            add(result, current);
        }
        current = current->next;
    }

    return result; 
}
```

I have the problem at runtime which is described in the image below (All the data in the txt files are exactly the same as the data model):

[image]

You could see the problem that the item on `Invoice2` would also appear on `Invoice1`, which is not true!

Comment: ***I believed that the there was something about memory allocation went wrong*** I believe that is doubtful however  you completely omitted that from your code so I can't be sure. However why are you making guesses at all. Don't guess what your code is doing use your debugger to see what your code is doing. Which means put in a small input and step through your code line by line in the debugger looking at the variables and flow after each individual line is executed. Don't just run your code in the debugger and hope it tells you anying, instead actively use it to see what is going wrong.

Comment: Now with Vlad's answer I see  the big problem is while your creating the second "result" list you corrupt the nodes in the first since you are sharing the same nodes between the 2 lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data member `next` of the node pointed to by the pointer `current` that is added to the new list is not set to `nullptr`.

First of all, either you need to create a dynamic copy of the node pointed to by the pointer `current` that is added to the new list, and set its data member `next` to `nullptr`.

Or, you need to remove from the source list the node that is added to the new list, also setting its data member `next` to `nullptr`.